# Sitecore website needs to compile?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, sitecore

I have been working for some time with sitecore.

Since my arrival, I have been taking the existing projects as a reference and creating new projects.

For Sitecore, we will have loads of folders and files for the website. We only need to create sublayouts (`*.ascx`) together with JavaScripts and CSS files.

For those `*.ascx` files, I put them under `layouts/Project_Name/The_File_Name.ascx` and `layouts/Project_Name/The_File_Name.ascx.cs`.

In a `*.ascx` file, I have the following.

```
<%@ Control Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="true" TargetSchema="http://schemas.microsoft.com/intellisense/ie5"  Inherits="Layouts.The_File_Name.The_File_NameSublayout" CodeFile="~/layouts/Project_Name/The_File_Name.ascx.cs" %>
```

After finishing, I deploy the whole layout folder onto the production server.

I will create a blank website on the production server and copy over the necessary files, mainly JavaScripts, CSS and `*.ascx` files.

Yesterday, A Sitecore consultant suggested that I change from `CodeFile` to `CodeBehind` and compile them.

I understand that if we create web application in Visual Studio, the system gives us `CodeBehind` and whenever we change, we need to compile.

But if we create a web site, we don't need to compile. We can however, publish the site.

My question is: what did the consultant mean? Do I need to compile the whole Sitecore website folder?

If so, can I compile (build) the whole folder?

And can I get the `*.dll` from it?

So far, i have tried to compile 2 of my sites and I am getting this error

> Could not load assembly or file ChilkaDotNet2 or one of its dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the consultant. There are two project types in Visual Studio:

1. Website Project
2. Web Application Project

Sitecore itself comes shipped as a compiled web app, so for you to add layouts, sublayouts and anything else into it, you **should** create a Web Application Project (WAP) in VS and only include your files in the project. When you do this, you then just need to deploy your project's `*.dll`'s to the target server's `/bin/` and any `*.aspx` or `*.ascx` files (no code behinds or designer files).

Now, in theory, you can create a WAP in VS and manually change `CodeBehind` to `CodeFile` but then you need to deploy the `*cs` files. In general, its recommend to use a web app so you can use automation processes like a build server or batch script to build your project.

The error message you posted is because you're trying to build the Website Project. A standard non-Sitecore Website Project can be built, but not if its Sitecore since Sitecore itself already exists as a compiled WAP and you cannot exclude files from the project from being built.

Here is a blog post by the CTO of Sitecore that may help you: [Create a Visual Studio 2010 Project for a Sitecore Solution](http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/09/Create-a-Visual-Studio-2010-Project-for-a-Sitecore-Solution.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's a great help. I have some questions though. Do I need to create the exact folder structure as `Sitecore` website like `layouts` and `xsl` folders? And when I followed the blog's instruction, in step 4, he asked to copy only `.csproj` and `.csproj.user` file and delete the whole folder which includes web.config and assemblyinfo file. Shouldn't we copy those things out also?

Comment: No, you will use the web.config which the Sitecore installer will deploy to the inetpub folder. Youll need to include this back into your project. The folder structure does not need to be exact, I personally structure it different. You will have to add the locations of the ascx/xsl files when you add Sublayouts or Renderings in Sitecore so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I see. So, this `web application` is just for the purpose of better security and clearer structure.

Comment: Not particularly. It's more to do with catching errors and exceptions in your code, at compile time rather than runtime. Much better to catch them at the earliest point!

Comment: Would it increase the website speed tremendously?

Comment: Its not necessarily faster since in any case, the first request after a deployment for WSP vs. WAP will compile or start the app. You should look at the general Microsoft guidelines on WSP vs WAP: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Comment: Hi all, can you answer this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432903/sitecore-inline-editing-on-other-items