# Sitecore inline editing on other items

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I was told to do `inline editing` for `Sitecore` web site.

It is working for the simple page like an article page.

`<sc:text ID="sct1" ruat="server" ... />`

But if the page is more complicated, it is impossible now, i believe.

Sample page like ..

`About Us` will have 3 different radio buttons.

According to the button chosen, the respective content will show. That content is actually a child content of `About Us`.

And if I want `inline editing`, i have to check whether it is the `editing mode`

If so, I can show all 3 set contents.

And the user can edit it. But when he saves, only the main page is saved. the child pages are not saved.

Do we have an alternate solution for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assertion is incorrect that when the page is saved, that only the item being rendered is saved. If you output a field from any item using a field renderer (as `sc:text` does behind the scenes), Sitecore will track that the item has been edited, and save the changes made.

You can populate the `Item` or `Datasource` property on `sc:text` in order to edit a field from another item.

Example syntax when data binding an `Item` object:

```
<sc:Text runat="server" ID="uxNameText" Field="Name" Item="<%#Container.DataItem%>" />
```

Or Datasource can be used to bind an item path (not recommended) or ID (a bit better):

```
<sc:Link Field="Link" DataSource="/sitecore/content/home" runat="server" />
```

You can also populate either `Item` or `Datasource` in your codebehind.

As an alternative, utilize a framework such as Custom Item Generator to create a .NET class that will allow you to easily output field values from any item in a way that will support inline editing.

References:

http://blog.velir.com/index.php/2010/10/19/custom-item-generator/

http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog?tag=custom+item+generator

Comment: I don't think I will be using `Custom Item Generator` as the site has already half way done and I cannot go to trac.sitecore.net to install the package. So, I must use `Sitecore controls` for all server controls in order to edit? do ur answer mean this code will work in `inlie editing`? `<sc:text ID="temp1" runat="server" Field="Title" DataSource="OtherID" />`

Comment: Yes you have it. I updated my answer with further detail.

Depending on your project timeline, you might consider refactoring to use Custom Items. Your future self and others maintaining your code will thank you.

Comment: All the trac references need to be updated to the new Sitecore Marketplace... Custom Item Generator can now be found: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Custom_Item_Generator.aspx

Comment: Total fail by Sitecore. They really should have setup 301 redirects.